# Generated sigma-algebras.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume you have two random varaibles $X,Y$ on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Define

$\sigma(X,Y)=\{(X(\omega),Y(\omega))^{-1}(B_2): B_2\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})\}$.

It it can be shown that $\sigma(X,Y)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and that $\sigma(X,Y)\subset \mathcal{A}$.

I am wondering if $\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))=\sigma(X,Y)$?
I am able to show $\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))\subset\sigma(X,Y)$, it is the other implication I have a problem with.

Does the statement hold or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\{E\subseteq \mathbb R^{2}: (X,Y)^{-1}(E) \in \sigma (\sigma (X) \cup \sigma (Y)\}$. Verify that this is a sigma algebra and that it contains all sets of the form  $E=A\times B$ whre $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb R$. This implies that this sigma algebra contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb R^{2}$. Hence  $\sigma (X,Y) \subseteq \sigma (\sigma (X) \cup \sigma (Y)) $

Comment: Thank you very much!